How to import only the new data and new records that have changed using the ETL process in a data warehouse?
I have an ETL process that allows me to load data from one database to another, applying transformations along the way. The process currently starts by deleting all records from all tables, and then reloading everything to avoid duplicates. Over time, this ETL process is taking a lot of time, as the data is being updated daily.
The solution I'm proposing is to import only the new records and the records that have changed in the last 6 months, instead of reloading the entire dataset each time. This would help improve the efficiency and speed of the ETL process.
How can I modify my ETL process to achieve this? In other words, how can I import just the new data and records that have changed in the last 6 months, without the need to delete and reload the entire dataset every time?
How can I modify my ETL process to achieve this? In other words, how can I import just the new data and records that have changed in the last 6 months, without the need to delete and reload the entire dataset every time?

Hi - I’m not sure why you would want to load records updated in the last 6 months rather than records updated since you last load? In any case, research change data capture (CDC) and incremental loads - as this is how most people would load a data warehouse there are numerous explanations/examples on the web. If you want specific help on this forum you’d need to provide a lot more detail (which DBMS, etc) and ask a specific question about a coding issue you are having

Since this is a general question, here is a general answer to get you in the right direction:

Find the changed files in the source system

Use CDC, like NickW suggested in the comments, if possible. This would get you new, changed and deleted records
If CDC is not an option, use a timestamp.  Store the last time of import in your target database and use this as a variable in your source queries.  DO NOT use the current date, so if there is a delay in processing, you never miss a day.  Also, do not fetch more data than you need to avoid reprocessing the same data every day.
If you do not have a timestamp, see if the source system can be modified to gather changed records.  i.e. add table triggers to stage changes or business keys into a staging table that you can import from.
Do not treat every table the same.  Every system has maybe 2 - 4 large tables surrounded by a myriad of small ones.  Import the small ones completely every time - this will be equally as fast and less error prone.  For the large tables, use the incremental strategies above.  Consider if you need to keep track of deleted records.  If the source system does soft deletes, get access to the underlying table so you can track the Active record flag.  If these are physical deletes and the source system has no tracking, you, indeed, might need to resort to fetching a larger time window that will ensure you have all the changes.


Stage and Update in the target system.

DO NOT use SSIS to perform inserts and updates, but instead, truncate and insert into staging tables in the target database and then call a proc to update the target table from the staging table.
Also, do all the transformations in the proc as well.  Use SSIS as an orchestrator and let the database do the heavy lifting.  This is going to be the best performing option.
Use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE.  For the staging tables, you should always use TRUNCATE -- this is much faster and avoids logging.  Do not put indexes on the staging tables and use TABLOCK when inserting into them.  This will create minimally logged transactions, which are much faster operations.
DO NOT use TRUNCATE with the target tables because this is a blocking operation, which requires a schema lock.  That would be disruptive to users or even block the loading process.  The experts prefer distinct UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE operations over MERGE, because the latter seems to have some ghosts in the machine, though I have never seen them.



